# kaltura javascript video tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html5-video

I'm trying to use the KDP javascript API to implement a .mp4 file in HTML5 using the Klatura player. This is my code so far:

`<div id="video" class="hide" >
<video name="player_123" id="player_123" width="330" type="video/mp4" height="480">
<source src="assets/91zVbVyKPSS.mp4" >
</video>
</div>`

How could I use the Javascript API with what I have? I have no idea how to configure it. It seems that it's trivial with the object tag but not the video tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to videojs.
Life is a little bit easier:
The point was, whatever you are about to do you should always use the HTML5 video tag. You should help the JS library of the video platform to identify the tag and everything should be automatic from there.